Looking for an old movie - A dog urinates on a man who is showering
I'm looking for an old movie. I'm not sure if it's foreign, but I recall that it's a comedy and I somewhat remember the opening scene.
A man returns home from late night work I assume, but it's early morning. While getting ready to take a shower, a dog passes by and pees through his window (he's on a basement/lower building floor) and he ends up being peed on while taking his shower.
I've been looking for this movie for more than 25 years. It reminds me of old childhood memories as it was my first VHS tape I played when I had my own room, tv, and vcr. I'd like to see this film again. I watched it with my now deceased mom and living alone in our home, that's one of the best memories I have. I'd really appreciate it if this community could help find this film... 

Hi. Do you know the film's approximate year\decade of release? The country\language?
